# Returning Parent Row in Grouped Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to identify the row number of the parent row belonging to a range which resides within a child row of the grouped rows.

In the picture attached, if I find 349594 in C264, I loop down the rows until I find a blank range (in this case C286) and then offset to find the value 1006C in A286.
I'm hoping that there is a simpler way of identifying the parent row (A288) of these grouped rows which has the same value of 1006C that I am looking for.

The existing loop runs for hundreds of products and it would be great if there was a way to do this more efficiently.

[image]

Edit:

This is a simplified version of what I am doing:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim SalesArr(1 To 1)
    SalesArr(1) = "349594" 'The actual array can have hundreds of sales order numbers
    
    Dim SearchVal As Range 'Range where the SalesArr value is found
    
    Set SearchVal = Range("C:C").Find _
    (What:=SalesArr(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    Do Until SearchVal.Value = vbNullString
        Set SearchVal = SearchVal.Offset(1) 'find the next empty range in C
    Loop
    
    Set SearchVal = SearchVal.Offset(, -2) 'find the product code
    
    Debug.Print SearchVal.Address 'in this case returns $A$286
    
End Sub
```

Is it possible to return A288, with it being the parent row of the group of rows in which the initial array value is found, rather than doing the loop?

Comment: You talk about finding `349594 ` but don't say why you find that instead of something else, you talk of a parent row, but don't define what that is in relationship to the number you looked for, etc... Your existing code and the problem you have with it would also be useful

Comment: Hi cybernetic, I am looping through an array of values of which 349594 is one.  The other 6 digits numbers may or may not appear in that array and I am only trying to find the ones that do.  When I do find a number which is in the array, and present on the worksheet, I then need to find the product to which it relates.  In the example, that product code resides in both A286 and A288.  The row in which the 6 digit number is found is always grouped and I was hoping that there was a way to identify the parent row of these grouped rows as that would make it easy to return A288 in the example.

Comment: When the Sales Order Number is found, it a set as a range object.  I then offset(1,0) until I find an empty string in C.  In the example that would be C286.  From there I offset(0,-2) to return the product code in A286.  I had the thought than when I find a value from the array, 349594 in this case, that rather than doing that loop that I've just explained, can I identify that the row on which it is found(264) is grouped and the parent row is 288?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68819498/edit) instead of adding information in comments some users may miss.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to the end of the current region and then go down one more row, something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    
    Dim SalesArr(1 To 1)
    SalesArr(1) = "349594" 'The actual array can have hundreds of sales order numbers
    
    Dim SearchVal As Range 'Range where the SalesArr value is found
    
    Set SearchVal = Range("C:C").Find _
    (What:=SalesArr(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    

    'Check for a blank cell immediately below the 'find' position - use xlDown if not.
    
    If SearchVal.Offset(1, 0) <> "" Then
        Set SearchVal = Range(SearchVal, Cells(Rows.Count, 3)).End(xlDown)
    End If
    
    Debug.Print SearchVal.Address
    
    Set SearchVal = SearchVal.Offset(1, -2) 'find the product code
    
    Debug.Print SearchVal.Address
    
    Debug.Print SearchVal.Value
    
End Sub
```

Output:

```
$C$10
$A$11
1006C
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input Tom.  The issue with xldown is, if the there is only one row of data, or the sales order is found on the last row, it wouldn't return the correct info.  In your screenshot, if C10 was the range where it was found and we used xldown it wouldn't work.  I suppose I could add an if statement to check if the row below the found range is blank and adjust accordingly.  Ultimately, I was hoping that there was a property of the range that could be used to identify if it was grouped and had a parent row but perhaps that's not possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right! It sounds as if you might be able to work with it, but I will adjust my answer in case other people want to use it.